Why Postgresql EXECUTE function is not displaying me any output?
So I have a crosstab query that looks something like this
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
        $q$
        SELECT ep, monitoring ->> 'type' AS type, (monitoring ->> 'status') AS status
        FROM job_monitoring
        WHERE monitoring ? 'type'
        ORDER BY ep, type
        $q$
    ) AS ct (ep VARCHAR, "CDC" TEXT, "DI" TEXT)

When I execute this it gives me proper result as



ep
CDC
DI




123231
false
true


221122
true
true



But when I put this into a query variable and try executing it with EXECUTE. I am not getting any output like this
DO $$
DECLARE
    query TEXT;
BEGIN
query :='SELECT * FROM crosstab(
            $q$
            SELECT ep, monitoring ->> ''type'' AS type, (monitoring ->> ''status'') AS status
            FROM job_monitoring
            WHERE monitoring ? ''type''
            ORDER BY ep, type
            $q$
        ) AS ct (ep VARCHAR, "CDC" TEXT, "DI" TEXT)';
        RAISE NOTICE '%', query;
execute query;
END $$;


Can anybody help me on what I am doing wrong
Reason I need to use query variable is because I need to dynamically update the query

A DO statement can never return any values. You will have to write a function to do that:
CREATE FUNCTION pg_temp.tempfunc()
RETURNS TABLE (
   a integer,
   b integer,
   c text
) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$DECLARE
   query text := 'SELECT 1, 42, ''sometext''';
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE query;
END;$$;

SELECT * FROM pg_temp.tempfunc();

 a │ b  │    c     
═══╪════╪══════════
 1 │ 42 │ sometext
(1 row)

This temporary function will be dropped automatically when your database session ends.

Any documentation on how I can achieve this

I have added an example how you could do that.
